# CheckboxField checked in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

How will i be able to recognise a check on the Checkboxfield.
Like if a user checks on a check box, a notification is generated.

BR,
Suppi

Comment: Never mind, i got the solution.

i used a setChangeListener for the CheckboxField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CheckBoxField class inherited from Field class, which means you should be able to create an action listener.

Use setActionListener method and override the fieldChanged method to do whatever you want.

```
checkBox.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
    public void fieldChanged(...params ... ) {
        //your code
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually there is no `ActionListener`, nor the `Field.setActionListener()` in BB API. It should use `FieldChangeListener` with `Field.setChangeListener(FieldChangeListener listener)` instead.